# Django validate unique charfield in admin console

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models with a `CharField` called `path`. On one of them I need to force it to end with `/` and on the other one anything but `/`. Also this field has to be unique and indexed. Here is the solution I came up with so far:

`Dir` model (must end in '/')

```
#   The path for sorting, e.g. /stuff/00-1/. Must be unique and is indexed for performance.
path = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True, db_index=True, blank=False, validators=RegexValidator(regex=r'^/[A-Za-z0-9/-_]+/$', message="Please enter a valid Dir Path")) 
...   
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #   If the path does not end in "/" add it.
    if not self.path.endswith("/"):
        self.path += "/"
    if not self.path.startswith("/"):
        self.path = "/" + self.path
    #  print the result
    print("Saving path {}".format(self.path))
    super(Dir, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

I have attempted a `try except` around the call to `super()` however that changes nothing. How to I tell the admin console to validate the data so I get a not unique error before it saves and crashes so the admin can change it?

**TL;DR** how do I get the red line to appear above a charfeild in the admin console if it fails custom regex validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom validation in admin, you need a custom form for it in order to code your specific logic. `save()` method in django is never a good place to do validation because it doesn't return anything to the user form. Check django doc on how to [have your own form for django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form). Check also [how to validate a django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: Solved it. MyMigration was messed up. What do you think of adding validation to delete()  (changing foreign keys that were assigned to it)